# How to intercept raw WCF request?

Tags: wcf

I want to log the raw request arriving to a WCF service. IIS logs and WCF tracing produce a ton of garbage that I do not want to try to parse. And `IDispatchMessageInspector` is too late in the process. e.g. When the client sends application/xml as request media type the service bails out by saying it only accepts text/xml but the message inspector is not hit at all.

Is there any way to achieve this?